# Orika how to exclude property of a shared object

Tags: orika

I have a bean with two fields referring to the same object:

```
public class Address {
    private String country, state;
}
public class AddressDTO {
    private String country, state;
}

public class Person {
    private Address homeAddress;
    private Address workAddress;
}
public class PersonDTO {
    private AddressDTO homeAddress;
    private AddressDTO workAddress;
}

final Address address = new Address("US", "AL");
final Person person = new Person(address, address);
```

Since homeAddress and workAddress refer to the same object, they are naturally mapped to the same addressDTO object, but is it possible to exclude some field from each? e.g. I tried this:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(Person.class, PersonDTO.class)
 .exclude("homeAddress.state").exclude("workAddress.country").byDefault().register();
```

But the result is still a complete object:

```
PersonDTO{homeAddress=AddressDTO{country='US', state='AL'}, workAddress=AddressDTO{country='US', state='AL'}}
```

Is it possible to configure that for the same source field, they need to map to two objects?